# "CORS header 'Origin' cannot be added" when running a XMLHttpRequest in an userscript

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, http-headers, cors, userscripts

I'm having an userscript which I'm running with FireMonkey, which on specific sites fires requests to my home server to retrieve some data. I've been using jQuery AJAX so far, which worked fine as long as I set some headers server-side to deal with CORS:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Method: POST");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Origin");
```

What I wanted to do now is to move away from jQuery, since the AJAX request was the only thing I really used it for up until that point, and instead tried to implement a request the classic XMLHttpRequest way. Unfortunately though, using XHR for some reason fails silently, with `readyState === 4` and `status === 0`.

Using the Browser Content Toolbox on Firefox I found a hidden CORS blockage error, with the reason being `CORS header 'Origin' cannot be added`, which I can barely find any information on other than `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` could be missing. Testing the script locally, the XHR's request headers don't show up any difference to the AJAX' ones (with exception of `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest`, which I'm setting manually for XHR). What could be the reason that the request fails? Is AJAX doing something which I'm missing?

I'm not using `GM_XMLHttpRequest` for the userscript since I've implemented my own boilerplate for requests which I'm also bundling into related local scripts of mine. I've read some opinions on using different request libraries though, like [superagent](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent), which I'm not quite sure of if they would work more properly with userscripts while also being lightweight. I'll gladly take any suggestions for an alternative.

I'm using Mozilla Firefox and FireMonkey for userscript hosting.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [`Origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Origin) is handled by the browser. It's one of several headers you're not allowed to modify.

Comment: I'm aware of that, I don't set it manually. But whichever instance is supposed to set it doesn't do so.

Comment: Maybe the firemonkey part is considered "elevated privileges" - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSOriginHeaderNotAdded

Comment: I've seen this before, I wasn't sure what "enhanced privileges" was supposed to mean, but it actually makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery AJAX is simply a `XMLHttpRequest` based function.

Userscripts with any userscript managers, in this case FireMonkey, can make 3 types of XHR requests, based on the **context**:

- `fetch` & `XMLHttpRequest` from `page` context (JS code injected into the webpage)
  Request will be sent from the page and subject to page CSP & CORS
- `fetch` & `XMLHttpRequest` from `userScript` context (FireMonkey) or `content` context (other managers)
  Request will be sent from the userscript and subject to CORS
- `GM.fetch|GM_fetch` (FireMonkey only) & `GM.xmlHttpRequest|GM_xmlhttpRequest` from `browser` context
  Request will be sent from the background js and not subject to CORS, but wont have credentials

[Forbidden header name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Forbidden_header_name) lists headers that are not allowed to be modified in Firefox (and other modern browsers).

FireMonkey also strips Forbidden headers from `GM.fetch|GM_fetch` & `GM.xmlHttpRequest|GM_xmlhttpRequest` but the following exceptions are allowed: *Cookie, Host, Origin, Referer*
(ref: FireMonkey Help under 'Forbidden header name')

To summarise, the only way to alter *Origin* header in a userscript is to use GM fetch|xmlHttpRequest.

Comment: I understand. But how does AJAX circumvent this then? Is there no way to do this with XMLHttpRequest myself?

Comment: @StrikeAgainst The simplest way is to compare the headers sent via jQuery AJAX & XMLHttpRequest and then add the missing headers.

Comment: Like I said, I already did that, but to no avail.

Comment: @StrikeAgainst I am not very familiar with jQuery AJAX.so unless I see the actual sent headers, I cant suggest anything.