# CORS preflight requests working with jQuery AJAX, but failing with native XmlHttpRequests in Firefox

Tags: ajax, firefox, cors, xmlhttprequest, preflight

[This question is based on an issue I had before but never managed to resolve.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66905999/cors-header-origin-cannot-be-added-when-running-a-xmlhttprequest-in-an-users)

I'm running an userscript via FireMonkey which regulary sends requests to my backend server, those using CORS since they are cross-domain. For testing purposes my response headers are currently set very loosely backend-side:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Method: POST");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");
```

Frontend-side my requests are sent via `jQuery AJAX`, looking roughly like this:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: this.queryURL,
    timeout: this.timeout,
    data: this.formData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: onSuccess,
    error: onError
});
```

Nothing special here, requests have been working fine ever since.

I want to get rid of `jQuery` now and use native `XmlHttpRequest` instead. The implementation looks like this:

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", this.queryURL);
xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
xhr.timeout = this.timeout;
xhr.ontimeout = onTimeout;
xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
    if (xhr.readyState !== 4 || xhr.status === 0)
        return;

    if (xhr.status !== 200)
        onError(xhr);
    else
        onSuccess(xhr.responseText);
};
xhr.send(this.formData);
```

For some reason the requests seem not to be sent anymore on Firefox, at least the network tab doesn't show any. Testing it on Chrome it still works, but I figured that the issue might have something to do with preflight requests, since I noticed something strange:

With jQuery AJAX:

[image: With jQuery AJAX]

With native XHR:

[image: With native XHR]

Using native XHR, Chrome seems to always have a first preflight request failing, with a second one being successful. This doesn't happen with `AJAX`. Not sure if this is helpful in any way, but could this explain why requests keep failing at all in Firefox, and how to resolve it?

Comment: What does the Console tab say?

Comment: Nothing either, unfortunately. Neither the web page nor the browser console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some more research I finally found out that this is actually a firefox-related issue with userscripts: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1715249